# Работа с файлами js

Tags: javascript, html

У меня 5 текстовых полей, в которых лежат некие значения.

Как реализовать экспорт и импорт в файл? Т.е суть в том, чтобы все введенные значения ушли в файл, и позже их можно было открыть.

Поиск в Google не дал результатов, ибо решения я нашел только на PHP.

Comment: В файл на клиенте или на сервере?

Comment: нет клиент-серверного всзаимодействия. локальная страничка с текстовыми полями которые при заполнении нужно вывести в файл, и допустим таких файликов много выбрали нужный загрузили все в свои текстовые поля.

Comment: File API. читайте внимательно. можно и читать из файлов и сохранять в файлы, не только в локальном хранилище, но и в любом месте. надо только уметь пользоваться js и поиском, как на сервере, так и на клинте.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**File System API** - не стандартизированное и не утверждённое *W3C* API, которой будет работать только в браузерах на движке *Blink*. Этот вариант подойдёт Вам только в том случае, если Вы пишите дополнение для *Chrome* или *веб-аппликацию* под конкретный браузер.

Если нет, то используйте стандартизированный [**FileReader API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), который [работает почти на всех современных браузерах](http://caniuse.com/#search=FileReader).

**Пример записи и чтения файла (или нескольких):**

HTML:

```
<input id="input" type="file">
<hr>
<textarea id="textarea"></textarea>
<hr>
<a id="download" href="">Скачать файл</a>
```

JavaScript:

```
var inputElement = document.getElementById('input'),
    downloadElement = document.getElementById('download'),
    textareaElement = document.getElementById('textarea');

downloadElement.style.display = 'none';

inputElement.onchange = function() {
  var fileList = this.files, // список указанных файлов
      textFile = fileList[0]; // для нашего примера берём один файл
  // Проверяем тип файла (текстовой файл)
  if (textFile.type == 'text/plain') {
    // Создаём новый FileReader, который и будет читать наш файл
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Событие успешного чтения
    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
      var text = event.target.result,
          blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
      // Ваши любые манипуляции с данными
      textareaElement.value = text;
      downloadElement.style.display = 'block';
      downloadElement.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      downloadElement.download = textFile.name;
    };
    // Событие ошибки
    reader.onerror = function() {
      alert('Ошибка чтения файла!');
    };
    // Читаем наш файл как текст
    reader.readAsText(textFile);
  } else {
    alert('Это не текстовой файл!');
  }
};

textareaElement.onkeyup = function() {
  // Обновляем ссылку скачивания файла
  // (ТОЛЬКО ДЛЯ ПРИМЕРА, СКРИПТ ВЫПОЛНЯЕТСЯ ПРИ КАЖДОМ НАЖАТИИ КЛАВИШИ)
  var text = this.value,
      blob = new Blob([text], { type: 'text/plain' });
  downloadElement.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
};
```

*П.С. Не могу добавить в ответ больше двух ссылок (из-за ограничения по репутации) но поиск по "FileReader API" даст вам множество дополнительных подсказок и примеров ;)*

Answer (score 7):

Есть несколько вариантов со своими преимуществами и недостатками.
Посмотрите предлагаемые решения [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080929/how-to-save-a-file-at-client-side-using-javascript).

Примеры решений:

1) генерировать файл и по ссылке предлагать пользователю его скачать.
Реализация:

```js
function download(text, name, type) {
  var a = document.getElementById("a");
  var file = new Blob([text], {type: type});
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = name;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="a">click here to download your file</a>
<button onclick="download('file text', 'myfilename.txt', 'text/plain')">Create file</button>
```

2) Использовать FileSystem API - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

См. также https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2011/08/Saving-generated-files-on-the-client-side

Answer (score -1):

Если вы хотите использовать javascript для этих целей, то вам подходит node.js

Comment: И каким же образом оно подходит?