# Javascript. Работа с файлами и папками

Tags: javascript

Хочу попробовать написать простенький текстовый редактор на javascript html и css, в котором хотелось бы **создавать новые файлы и папки**.
Есть ли какие нибудь js-библиотеки для решения этих задач?

Comment: Вам стоит учесть, что, вероятнее всего, работать с файлами и папками в дальнейшем (если дальнейшее развитие планируется, конечно), будет сервер, а не JavaScript, потому как JavaScript сможет работать только на клиентской машине. Если подразумевается, что речь идет о браузерном JS.

Comment: @smellyshovel Нет, дальнейшего развитие не планируется) эт так для практики! И конечно же использую браузерный js

Comment: В таком случае имеет смысл почитать вот это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/429771/200881 , потому как насколько я знаю, работа с файлами вообще не предусмотрена (а ведь зачем? Нужно что-то сохранить - пиши в куки или в Storage).

Comment: Какой-то полный абсурд! Я хочу создать простенький текстовый редактор, есть что-нибудь готовое для этого. Есть! Тысяча и один бесплатный редактор. Если Вы будите использовать уже готовое то какой смыл это делать?

Comment: @OlmerDale Получения опыта!

Comment: @OlmerDale написали же, что в целях самообразования. Автор, нет никаких проблем в том, что вы хотите сделать, кроме сохранения. Либо обяжите сервер заниматься этим, либо пишите куда-нибудь в другие места.

Comment: @smellyshovel FileSystem API дает то что нужно, но жалко что поддерживается только в Chrome(

Comment: Поэтому я и написал, что нет проблем кроме этого. API не утверждено W3C, а значит использовать его не стоит.

Comment: По моему опыт получают при разработки библиотек которые Вы хотите чтобы Вам дали. И в моем понимании редактор, это приложение которое запускают в ОС. Если Вы хотите сделать такой, то это нода, в ней и папки и файлы можно создавать. Если же речь о вэб, то это не редактор, а текстовое поле. С созданием файловой структуры, если честно сказать, я не уверен что получится. Но вот можно попробовать копнуть в сторону расширений для браузера и там возможно такая возможность появится.

Comment: @OlmerDale Вы имеете ввиду node.js "**то это нода**"?

Comment: да, я о nodejs.

Comment: Не лучший выбор задачи для javascript. Создание и сохранение сторонних файлов (не cookie) противоречит безопасности, имхо, поэтому нативно в js не реализовано (поправьте, если ошибаюсь). Напишите калькулятор, и потренируетесь, и файлы создавать не надо :)

Comment: @Denisoed вы не хотите попрактиковаться и создать игру с помощью js ?

Comment: @stack-it Это просто вопрос или предложение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтоб написать простенький редактор, вам нужно будет изучить node.js и воспользоваться [Electron](http://electron.atom.io/).
Электрон позволит вам создать, что-то вроде Atom.io, но без базовых знаний в node.js вы далеко не уйдете.
Илья Кантор снял [скринкасты по node.js](https://learn.javascript.ru/screencast/nodejs), хоть там древняя версия, апи сильно не изменился, материал дает отличный старт для понимая как работает nodejs и как она взаимодействует с файловой системой.

Comment: Ответ то что надо! Спасибо)